# Map C struct with union field to Go struct

Tags: c, go, unsafe

I'm getting results from syscall to some WinApi in Go. I map simple structs from C code easily, but how to deal with C structs like the following?

```
typedef struct SPC_LINK_
{
    DWORD dwLinkChoice;
#               define          SPC_URL_LINK_CHOICE         1
#               define          SPC_MONIKER_LINK_CHOICE     2
#               define          SPC_FILE_LINK_CHOICE        3

    union
    {
        LPWSTR                  pwszUrl;
        SPC_SERIALIZED_OBJECT   Moniker;
        LPWSTR                  pwszFile;
    };

} SPC_LINK, *PSPC_LINK;
```

If all possible types are defined in Go

```
type SPC_LINK struct {
    dwLinkChoice  DWORD
    Moniker       SPC_SERIALIZED_OBJECT
    pwszFile      LPWSTR
    pwszUrl       LPWSTR
}
```

after the syscall with `unsafe.Pointer` to this Go struct as a parameter, I've got it in memory and can access it in Go as usual, but only the first field after `dwLinkChoice` (`Moniker` in the code above) is always filled, the other two are always empty. I know this is expected behavior in C, as you can have only one union field at a time. Taking this into account, should I ignore the whole union structure and have some sort of a placeholder in my Go struct?

```
type SPC_LINK struct {
    dwLinkChoice  DWORD
    dwLink        uintptr // a placeholder, will hold any possible value
}
```

I set type for the placeholder to uintptr, but what if the original C structure has some other non-pointer types in the union block? I'm really not sure how to handle C unions and looking for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [cgo documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/),

> As Go doesn't have support for C's union type in the general case, C's union types are represented as a Go byte array with the same length.

Maybe you should try this

```
type SPC_LINK struct {
    dwLinkChoice  DWORD
    dwLink        [{size of the union}]byte
}
```

Comment: thanks, I assume, the `{size of the union}` would be the longest of the union types