# Create FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR in Golang

Tags: windows, go, ntfs, usn

I'm trying to create this structure in Golang -

```
typedef struct FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR {
  DWORD        dwSize;
  FILE_ID_TYPE Type;
  union {
    LARGE_INTEGER FileId;
    GUID          ObjectId;
    FILE_ID_128   ExtendedFileId;
  } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
} FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR, *LPFILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR;
```

As you can see, this depends on union of three in which unknown is `FILE_ID_128` and another structure called `FILE_ID_TYPE` so I stumbled upon [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_file_id_128), which is `FILE_ID_128`s and the `_FILE_ID_TYPE`  structure is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/ne-winbase-_file_id_type) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bb870609)

```
typedef enum _FILE_ID_TYPE {
  FileIdType,
  ObjectIdType,
  ExtendedFileIdType,
  MaximumFileIdType
} FILE_ID_TYPE, *PFILE_ID_TYPE;
```

And doing after doing some research, I found out that [enum is const in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426366/what-is-an-idiomatic-way-of-representing-enums-in-go) but in Go, *we can not have a named const so maybe a struct(?)* and [union are byte slices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50444766/6104077). But I could not find what `MaximumFileIdType` meant and how to implement that in Go. Thanks in advance.

Also, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763195/how-to-get-the-full-path-for-usn-journal-query) that I am following.

Comment: What do you mean "we cannot have a named const"?

Comment: What is mean is enums are named in the link that I've provided and used in a different structures but in Go, consts are plain `const (somevar = 1)`

Comment: In your example, the name of your const is `somevar`.

Comment: No, what I mean is, for example in C, we define `typedef enum _FILE_ID_TYPE` and use `_FILE_ID_TYPE` in struct `FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR ` but in Golang, we just say `const (somevar = 1)`, so how do I implement `_FILE_ID_TYPE `? I have posted another link in the answer regarding `FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR `

Comment: So you mean that Go doesn't support enums, not that it doesn't support named constants?

Comment: Yes, go does not support enums. But I found out enums in C are but consts in Go. Then how do I implement `enum _FILE_ID_TYPE` in Go?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not get that @AlexF

Comment: @ThatBird, [`enum`s in C use `int` as their underlying type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum), and have no magic in them: an enum value may be used whereever a plain constant or a value (both of type `int` may be used). Enums have integer values—assigned either automatically (0, 1, …) or manually, and so to emulate a C's enum in Go, you should to two steps: 1) figure out what is the size of `int` in C on your target platform; 2) use one of `intXY` types on your Go side so that its size matches that found on step (1).

Comment: I always found enums to be a painful and bizarre practice in programming and I am baffled by the many questions from programmers coming from other languages to Go trying to reintroduce them

Comment: @ThatBird, as to "idiomatic enums", yes, there exist typed constants; you can do something like `const ( foo = int(0); bar = int(1); )` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is ready to use code (taken from [here](https://github.com/gentlemanautomaton/volmgmt), with *fix applyed*: in repo the worng size of struct is set, which results in `invalid prameter (87)` error):

```golang
/*Must put file id into ID as big endian; 
little endian form will be placed in descriptor 
automatically when calling id.Descriptor()*/
type ID [16]byte 

func (id ID) Descriptor() Descriptor {
    var structType uint32
    if id.IsInt64() {
        structType = FileType
    } else {
        structType = ExtendedFileIDType
    }

    return Descriptor{
        Size: 24, // (1)
        Type: structType,
        Data: id.LittleEndian(),
    }
}

func (id ID) IsInt64() bool {
    upper := int64(id[0])<<56 | int64(id[1])<<48 | int64(id[2])<<40 | int64(id[3])<<32 | int64(id[4])<<24 | int64(id[5])<<16 | int64(id[6])<<8 | int64(id[7])
    return upper == 0
}

func (id ID) LittleEndian() (value [16]byte) {
    for i := 0; i < 16; i++ {
        value[i] = id[15-i]
    }
    return
}

type Descriptor struct {
    Size uint32
    Type uint32
    Data [16]byte
}

const (
    FileType = iota
    ObjectIDType
    ExtendedFileIDType
)
```

#### Some explanation:

**(1)** size always must be 24 since it must be equal to `sizeof(FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR)`, which is calculated as follows:

`sizeof(DWORD) + sizeof(enum) + sizeof(union)`

since `DWORD` is `uint32` the `sizeof(DWORD)` is 4 bytes; in C++ enums are represented as `uint32` too; and `sizeof(union)` equals the size of largest member of union, which is `FILE_ID_128` in our case. size of 128 bit value is 16 bytes.
Therefore the above expression can be substituted with:

`4 + 4 + 16 = 24`